# Unable to start service Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.company.callrecorder/.CallStateListener }: not found

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-intent

I'm trying to record calls. But there is a big issue in starting service intent.

> WARN/ActivityManager(61): Unable to start service Intent { flg=0x10000000     >cmp=com.company.callrecorder/.CallStateListener }: not found

This is my Broadcastreceiver code:

```
        public class StartServicesAtStartUp extends BroadcastReceiver
```

{
        public static Intent phoneStateListener;
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "com.its.CallRecorder Initiated ...");
                Toast.makeText(context," Call Recording Initiated.. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Start_CallRec(context);
        }

```
    public static void Start_CallRec(Context context)
    {
        if(!SharedData._Started )
        {
            if(SharedData._AutoStart)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context," Call Recording Auto-Start.. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                phoneStateListener = new Intent(context, CallStateListener.class);
                phoneStateListener.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startService(phoneStateListener);
                Log.d("DEBUG", "com.its.CallRecorder Call Recorder Started ...");
                TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                CallStateListener callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
                tManager.listen(callStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
                SharedData._Started = true;
                Toast.makeText(context," Call Recording Started ... ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context," Call Recording Already Active.. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public static void Stop_CallRec(Context context)
    {
        if(SharedData._Started )
        {
            context.stopService(phoneStateListener);
            Toast.makeText(context," Call Recording Stopped  ... ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            SharedData._Started = false;                
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(context," Call Recording Already Stopped  ... ",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

}

And CallStateListener.java code is:

```
public class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
{
    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    switch(state)
    {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        if(SharedData._Recording) 
            { Recorders_Stop(); }
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
        String CallDate = SanityDate();
        String CallNum = SanityNum(incomingNumber);
        String RootDir = SharedData._Path ;  
        String CallDir = SharedData._Path + CallNum + "/" ;
        String CallFile = SharedData._Path +  CallNum + "/" + CallNum + "-" + CallDate ;
        if(!SharedData._Recording)
        {
            SharedData._Recording = true;
            String med_state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if(!med_state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
                { break; }

            File directory = null;
            directory = new File(RootDir + "text.txt" ).getParentFile();
            if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs())
                { break; }

            directory = new File(CallDir + "text.txt" ).getParentFile();
            if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs())
                { break; }

            Recoders_Init(CallFile);
            Recorder_Prepare();
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to record calls.

This is not possible, except perhaps when in speakerphone mode.

> But there is a big issue in starting service intent.

That is because you do not have a `Service`. You have a `BroadcastReceiver`. A `BroadcastReceiver` is not a `Service`. You cannot call `startService()` with an `Intent` identifying a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer CommonsWare. I succeeded recording calls with this code without using speakerphone. The issue is based on recording with different types like: .3gp, .mp4 and .amr. When I fix the problem of re-starting mediarecorder, the problem is solved spontaneously.